# Vue 2 Watched properties are not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

Well, I have 4 dropdowns in a row where I dynamically set the subsequent options depending on the selected option with AJAX. But for some reason, the watcher methods are not being called anymore.

[image: Dropdowns]

> **Translation**
>
> Country: *Choose a country*
>
> Department: *Choose a department*
>
> Location: *Choose a location*
>
> Zone: *Choose a zone*

This is the HTML code that belongs to the previous form section:

```
<div class="row">
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <label for="country" class="control-label">Pa&iacute;s</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" v-model="selectedCountry" @change="selectCountry()">
            <option :value="0" :selected="selectedCountry">Elija un pa&iacute;s</option>
            <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.id">@{{ country.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <label for="department" class="control-label">Departamento</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="department" id="department" v-model="selectedDepartment" @change="selectDepartment()">
            <option :value="0" :selected="selectedDepartment">Elija un Departamento</option>
            <option v-for="department in departments" :value="department.id">@{{ department.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <label for="location" class="control-label">Localidad</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="location" id="location" v-model="selectedLocation" @change="selectLocation()">
            <option :value="0" :selected="selectedLocation">Elija una localidad</option>
            <option v-for="location in localities" :value="location.id">@{{ location.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <label for="zone" class="control-label">Zona</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="zone" id="zone" v-model="selectedZone">
            <option :value="0" :selected="selectedZone">Elija una zona</option>
            <option v-for="zone in zones" :value="zone.id">@{{ zone.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Of course, this is inside a `<div id="app"></div>`. This is the Javascript:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        ...
        countries: [],
        departments: [],
        localities: [],
        zones: [],
        ...
    },
    mounted: function() {
        ...
        this.loadCountries(5);
        this.loadDepartments(5);
        this.loadLocalities(5);
        this.loadZones(5);
        ...
        if(!this.selectedCountry) {
            $('#department').val("");
            $('#department').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        if(!this.selectedDepartment) {
            $('#location').val("");
            $('#location').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        if(!this.selectedLocation) {
            $('#zone').val("");
            $('#zone').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.expenses = expensesValue;
        this.selectedCountry = formSelectedCountry;
        this.selectedDepartment = formSelectedDepartment;
        this.selectedLocation = formSelectedLocation;
        this.selectedZone =  formSelectedZone;
    },
    methods: {
        ...
        loadCountries: function(total) {
            axios.get('/api/inmuebles/paises/')
                .then(function (response) {
                    app.countries = response.data;
                });

            total = (total <= this.countries.length) 
                ? total 
                : this.countries.length;

            if(total) {
                var newArr = [];
                for(i=0; i<total; i++) {
                    newArr.push(this.countries[i]);
                }
                this.countries = newArr;
            }            
        },
        loadDepartments: function(total) {
            axios.get('/api/inmuebles/departamentos/')
                .then(function (response) {
                    app.departments = response.data;
                });

            total = (total <= this.departments.length) 
                ? total 
                : this.departments.length;

            if(total) {
                var newArr = [];
                for(i=0; i<total; i++) {
                    newArr.push(this.departments[i]);
                }
                this.departments = newArr;
            }        
        },
        loadLocalities: function(total) {
            axios.get('/api/inmuebles/localidades/')
                .then(function (response) {
                    app.localities = response.data;
                });

            total = (total <= this.localities.length) 
                ? total 
                : this.localities.length;

            if(total) {
                var newArr = [];
                for(i=0; i<total; i++) {
                    newArr.push(this.localities[i]);
                }
                this.localities = newArr;
            }        
        },
        loadZones: function(total) {
            axios.get('/api/inmuebles/zonas/')
                .then(function (response) {
                    app.zones = response.data;
                });

            total = (total <= this.zones.length) 
                ? total 
                : this.zones.length;

            if(total) {
                var newArr = [];
                for(i=0; i<total; i++) {
                    newArr.push(this.zones[i]);
                }
                this.zones = newArr;
            }        
        },
        selectCountry: function() {
            if(this.selectedCountry < 1) { return; }
            axios.get('/api/inmuebles/pais/' + this.selectedCountry)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    if(data.departments.length > 0) {
                        var departments = [];
                        $.each(data.departments, function (index, value) {    
                            departments.push(value);
                        });
                        app.departments = departments;
                    }
                });
        },
        selectDepartment: function() {
            if(this.selectDepartment < 1) { return; }
            axios.get('/api/inmuebles/departamento/' + this.selectedDepartment)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    if(data.localities.length > 0) {
                        var localities = [];
                        $.each(data.localities, function (index, value) {
                            localities.push(value);
                        });
                        app.localities = localities;
                    }
                });
        },
        selectLocation: function() {
            if(this.selectedLocation < 1) { return; }
            axios.get('/api/inmuebles/localidad/' + this.selectedLocation)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    if(data.zones.length > 0) {
                        var zones = [];
                        $.each(data.zones, function (index, value) {
                            zones.push(value);
                        });
                        app.zones = zones;
                    }
                });
            },
        ...
        },
        watch: {
            selectedCountry: function(value) {
            if(value > 0) {
                $('#department').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#department').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#location').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#zone').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                this.selectedDepartment = null;
                this.selectedLocation = null;
                this.selectedZone = null;
            }
        },
        selectedDepartment: function(value) {
            if(value > 0) {
                $('#location').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#location').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#zone').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                this.selectedLocation = null;
                this.selectedZone = null;

            }
        },
        selectedLocation: function(value) {
            if(value > 0) {
                $('#zone').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#zone').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                this.selectedZone = null;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Do you see the problem, or any problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With so much code, it would help to put this in a jsFiddle or something where we could see the actual problem. One thing that stands out to me is the mixing of jQuery and Vue.  You need to pick which technology is going to manage the DOM -- Vue or jQuery.  Mixing the two can cause issues at each one competes to modify the DOM.

Comment: Do not change data directly, use [set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).